# selenium-jupiter - Connecto to seleniumGrid for testTemplates

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid, junit5, selenium-jupiter

Is it possible to combine the annotation `@TestTemplate` with the `@DriverUrl` so that I can run the tests on my Selenium Grid?

Thanks 
Christian

Answer (score 0):

`@TestTemplate` can be combined with `@DriverUrl` in Selenium-Jupiter as of version 3.1.0. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-jupiter/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/seljup/test/template/TemplateRegisterRemoteTest.java).